# Qual o melhor Design Pattern para Logger em Java

Tags: java, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software

Gostaria de saber qual é a melhor escolha para implementar loggers em Java.

Atualmente eu tenho utilizado inversão de dependência como o exemplo a seguir:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/");
public class HomeController
{
    private final LoggerImpl logger;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(LoggerImpl logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView home(){
        this.logger.log(new LogBean("Ação"));
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

Logo segue a interface:

```
public interface Loggable
{
    void log(LogBean logBean);
}
```

E sua implementação:

```
@Component
public class LoggerImpl implements Loggable
{
    private final LoggerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public LoggerImpl(LoggerRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void log(LogBean logBean){
        ...
        this.repository.save(logBean);
        ...
    }
}
```

Do jeito que está funciona, mas... Acho muito repetitivo esse modelo. 
Gostaria que alguém consiga me dar uma luz do que pode ser feito ou melhorado.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que é difícil responder essa pergunta sem incorrer em opinião. Mas qualquer solução que exija criar um membro em um tipo para fazer uma coisa que não seja algo relacionado diretamente com o tipo, eu tô fora, isso é um erro. Eu sei que tem gente que pensa diferente. Pra mim é insano o tipo fazer mais do que sua responsabilidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bigown, quando a o que você disse ocorre exatamente com sua afirmação de que a pergunta incorre em opinião. E por notar que o modelo implementado não está de acordo com o meu gosto e ideologia vim tentar alguma opinião.

Comment: O log precisa estar em toda parte mas é algo ortogonal à sua aplicação. Se você remover todo o log ela continua a funcionar. Ler o código fonte que emite log não deveria ser relevante para entender a aplicação, então quanto mais transparente ele estiver, melhor. Em suma: não suje os construtores com injeção de logger, deixe sua API ignorante de log. Obtenha o logger de um método estático, a exemplo do log4j ou do [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html), mais ou menos assim: `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MinhaClasse.class);`

Comment: Olá Caffé, no caso você me sugere um LoggerFactory?

Comment: Sim. Mas eu não implementaria o factory, tampouco o próprio logger. Eu uso log4j como implementação de logger e o SLF4J para abstraí-lo, de modo a facilitar integração com o log emitido por bibliotecas ou frameworks que usam outras implementações de log (alguns frameworks usam por exemplo a implementação nativa do Java).